# Can you make an iPhone OS 2.x app compatible with iOS 4.x without access to the source code?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have some apps that where created for iPhone OS 2.x, and I really want to make them compatible with iOS 4.x / iOS 5.0.

The only problem is I don't have the source code.  Is there a way to bring these apps up to date and make them compatible with modern iOS versions if I don't have the original code for them?

Comment: Are these your applications?  If so, how in the world did you lose your own source code for them?  If not, you'll need to contact the original developer to obtain the code and the permission to modify it.

Answer (score 2):

please forget of porting. porting means upgrading your old source code according to new software version and in your case there is no source code.

fresh development is the only solution left for you i'm afraid!

Comment: So there is no way to make it run on iOS 4 ? Because this application i'm talking about is Installer 2. And i can't re code that :(

Comment: actually there are hell lot of changes in the APIs and Classes since version 2x - 4x/5x. No 2x compiled application will be able to run properly on any 4.x/5.x platform.